# Why does Chrome wrap inline list items more than Firefox or IE?

Tags: css, html, layout, google-chrome

I've been updating a template to HTML5, and run into a strange problem with Chrome. I've put unordered lists into <nav> elements for the menus, and added padding to separate them slightly. The width of the <nav> is sufficient to contain all the list items in all three of the browsers on my system: IE9, FF5 and Chrome (current).

However, Chrome is the only one that wraps the items onto two lines.

Here's the test layout:

http://www.tubbs.org.uk/html5/

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

(I'm aware, BTW, of many, many errors from the use of a DokuWiki stylesheet before its colours have been through the preprocessor.)

Comment: you're using class names like "main box" which equates to "main" *and* "box". Change to "mainBox" or similar. May be your fix. Regards,

Comment: @user247245: That's by design. The main nav element is distinguished by class main, and is also a box that needs the visual formatting.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tubbs.org.uk/html5/

The top bar is broken in Firefox 6.0 beta as well.

One thing I've noticed is that you're using percentage padding which is generally a bad idea for cross-browser compatability.

Try using a px value for padding instead: 0 10px vs 0 1.5%

Comment: if you fix your padding to pixels on `nav.main li` and `nav li` this fixes the problem

Comment: Not for me, unfortunately; I've set both to 10px and still have the last link on a second line, despite the room for it above. Same occurs with 1em, and meanwhile the bar attached to the top of the page works with all...

Comment: nav.main li {
padding: 0 8px;
}

Comment: That does indeed get them all on one line, but there's patently room for them even when it's set to 15px or more.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome seems to be applying padding from two different rules: 
nav.main li (3%), if that's disabled it applies the padding from nav li( 1.5%). If both of those rules are disabled it renders all of them on one row.

It is probably how webkit is interpreting the padding: line. You may want to try doing 
padding-left, padding-right and see if that helps.

You can also use the chrome developer's toolkit (Ctrl+shift+I) and use it to enable or disable various styles to see how they're being applied.

Comment: True; when there's no padding involved, they do render on one line. I'm wondering what's causing FF5 and IE9 to get this "right", while Chrome (and now FF6, apparently) think they need to wrap.

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't really find what is a sensible reason other than maybe it's webkit browsers are treating it as a different kind of block than IE9 and FF5.